# django-selectable LookupAlreadyRegistered error

Tags: django, autocomplete

i am trying django-selectable the 'fruit' example given in the docs here -
https://django-selectable.readthedocs.org/en/version-0.6.2/quick-start.html#defining-a-lookup

getting  LookupAlreadyRegistered error,there is a small note on this error,but i can't
figure out how to solve this.i understand that it has something to do with import statements, i am using django-1.3

i will provide more info if needed , but i am just using the same code as given in the example.

kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the note in the link you've posted:

> You should only register your lookup once. Attempting to register the same lookup class more than once will lead to LookupAlreadyRegistered errors. A common problem related to the LookupAlreadyRegistered error is related to inconsistant import paths in your project. Prior to Django 1.4 the default manage.py allows for importing both with and without the project name (i.e. from myproject.myapp import lookups or from myapp import lookups). This leads to the lookup.py file being imported twice and the registration code executing twice. Thankfully this is no longer the default in Django 1.4. Keeping your import consistant to include the project name (when your app is included inside the project directory) will avoid these errors.

Comment: @ Augusto Men yes sir, i have read the note,but could not understand how to solve the problem,can you help me understand how the lookup.py is being imported twice? pardon my ignorance,i am new to django

Comment: @Ananth For a start, according to the note, you may search everywhere in your code where you import `lookups`, and see if the statements are different. If they include the project name, that may be causing the problem.

Comment: Found the source of the error in a urls file, i have been importing my forms file from the project,changed to it to exclude the project name from the import statement and it works,thanks